# How to change 3g dns setting on Android?

Tags: android

I want to change 3G dns setting on Android 2.1 device. I managed to install busybox on my device, i can also get dns information by using `adb shell getprop | grep dns`. The only problem is that it shows me `net.pdp0.dns1` and `net.pdp0.dns2`, not `net.rmnet0.dns1` and `net.rmnet0.dns1` so i can't change the setting.

I know that `net.rmnet0.dns1` is for 3G connection, so what about `net.pdp0.dns1`? How can i change to `net.rmnet0.dns1`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Android DSN file contains in following directory:**

**In android file system

system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/20-dns.conf**

20-dns.conf file contains dns setting, you can modify this file by following way:

```
# Set net.<iface>.dnsN properties that contain the
# DNS server addresses given by the DHCP server.

set_dns_props()
{
    case "${new_domain_name_servers}" in
    "")   return 0;;
    esac

    count=1
    for i in 1 2 3 4; do
        setprop dhcp.${interface}.dns${i} ""
    done

    count=1
    for dnsaddr in ${new_domain_name_servers}; do
        setprop dhcp.${interface}.dns${count} ${dnsaddr}
        count=$(($count + 1))
    done

    setprop dhcp.eth0.dns1 8.8.8.8
    setprop dhcp.eth0.dns2 8.8.8.4
}

unset_dns_props()
{
    for i in 1 2 3 4; do
        setprop dhcp.${interface}.dns${i} ""
    done
}

case "${reason}" in
BOUND|INFORM|REBIND|REBOOT|RENEW|TIMEOUT)       set_dns_props;;
EXPIRE|FAIL|IPV4LL|RELEASE|STOP)                unset_dns_props;;
esac
```

**(Note:Please take backup of origin file , if you need origin file)**

**set your dns in following line**

```
setprop dhcp.eth0.dns1 8.8.8.8
setprop dhcp.eth0.dns2 8.8.8.4
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you state the kind of device you have. From what I've read online, Samsung devices use the pdp0 interface names (it may be that this is the way Samsung refers to the 3G connections). Personally I have been using all HTC devices and the 3G interface is always rmnet0.

Is your phone rooted? You may not be able to set properties in the "net" category without root permissions.

If you are root, have you tried "setprop net.pdp0.dns1 "? Also, does "adb shell getprop | grep dns" give you "net.dns1"? I believe this is the default way Android looks up DNS servers. You may want to set this property as well.

You can test if it is working by running nslookup, it will show you the server it is querying.

Good luck,
B-Rad